# How do I create subviews for each view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I don't really understand exactly how routing works. I haven't had a problem with it until now because my views have all been very simple. I am currently making an admin view for the owner of the site to control the page, but I would like each option in the admin view to have its own "subview", so I can access things like:

> /Admin/**Content**/Create[Edit][Details][Delete] 
>   /Admin/**Settings**/Create[Edit][Details][Delete] 
>   /Admin/**Users**/Create[Edit][Details][Delete]

Instead of having to create views like:

> /Admin_**Content**/Create[Edit][Details][Delete] 
>   /Admin_**Settings**/Create[Edit][Details][Delete] 
>   /Admin_**Users**/Create[Edit][Details][Delete]

.. Which would be the only way I understand how to do it now.

Im not sure how to explain it in any other way, other than I want to have "A view in a view"

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question even is, I think you're just saying you don't understand how routing works? Did you look at some tutorials and try something that didn't work? If not, you should... this is pretty broad if you're just asking for us to explain it to you. When  I was learning routing I found this tutorial very helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a view that has subviews. So In /Admin I can access a view called /Content or /Setttings and then access Create, Edit, Details, Delete from there. So it would look like /Admin/Content/Create or /Admin/Settings/Create - Is it possible to do something like this? Having access to some views, only inside /Admin ?

Sorry if Im bad a explaining this.

Comment: I think you were looking for partial view. Google search for PARTIAL VIEW in mvc, it would be the solution for you.

Comment: @SeverinDK Yes, that is possible.

Comment: @SeverinDK Is partial view enough to solve your issue?

Comment: @RajeshKannan - I don't think so. I want the admin to be able to access what he wants either by clicking a link in the root of the admin panel or just change the url. Let's say he is in /Admin and wants to update something in Content, then he would go to /Admin/Content/Edit 

Both Admin and Content are views. Im not sure if this is even the correct way of doing it? Having quite a hard time wrapping my head around this. I've only been at MVC for about a week.

Comment: You should have Admin as a menu and Content, Settings as SubMenu. Under Content submenu, use Html.ActionLink or Html.RouteLink for the view links like Create, Edit etc.. Don't get confused. Also have a look into Routing in MVC.

Comment: I finally found what I was looking for: http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html

But I appreciate the answers either way :-) Thanks.

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for is called Area.
I found my solution here:
 http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html